# Routing incoming emails to different servers based on email address

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite

I use Google Apps for my company email. We would like certain emails to be handled by an application. These emails are part of the service we provide. So, what we want is:

emails to `application@mycompany.com` get handled by a special mail server
emails to `joe@mycompany.com` get handled by Google Apps

I want both emails to have the same domain.

I could set up a route within Google Apps, but `application@mycompany.com` gets a lot of email very frequently. Google Apps has throttling, I need to make sure this email is NOT throttled.

How can I route incoming emails to different mailservers?

Comment: Since it sounds like you are primarily concerned with incoming emails, does Google throttle aliases?

Comment: @Paul I believe that they throttle all incoming email.

Comment: The [Receiving limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366776?hl=en) page states that reaching throttling limits will prevent a user from receiving further mail. However, would an alias pointing to an email address hosted on a different server experience the same issue? Not clear to me by the statement on that page as an alias does not have to be a user, IIRC.